# "The handle is invalid" error when using Console methods in C# Interactive

Tags: c#, console, int, boolean, c#-interactive

When I use Console functions such as `SetCursorPosition` or `Clear`, I get an error saying the handle is invalid.

Example:

```
> Write("aaa");SetCursorPosition(0, 0);Write("b")
aaaThe handle is invalid.

  + System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(int, string)
  + System.Console.GetBufferInfo(bool, out bool)
  + System.Console.GetBufferInfo()
  + System.Console.SetCursorPosition(int, int)
  + <Initialize>.MoveNext()

> Write("bbb");Clear();
bbbThe handle is invalid.

  + System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(int, string)
  + System.Console.GetBufferInfo(bool, out bool)
  + System.Console.Clear()
```

How do I fix this and be able to use these functions in the C# Interactive window?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: It wouldn't really make sense to use those functions in interactive mode. There is no console window to actually clear or set cursor position within. As you may notice, your Write calls should work just fine if you do them by themselves.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb There is a console, since things are getting written. The `Write` function is part of `System.Console`, so there must be a console

Comment: @ddadfdalo - That doesn't matter. It's a false assumption that because it's in `System.Console` means it uses a console. The output can be redirected (disclaimer: I have **no idea** if this is what the interactive window does). If you do something like `Console.SetOut(new StreamWriter(@"C:\some_folder\my_file.txt"));` it will write to that file and you won't see anything in the console window at all.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb So can I use `SetCursorPosition` in a file once I redirect the output?

Comment: @ddadfdalo - I wouldn't think so (but I haven't tried). It just redirects where the output goes, but I would be sort of surprised if it treated the file itself as a console window.